# boto3 paginator, check multiple values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pagination, boto3

I've created a python function that takes in two parameters, the Environment name and a tag called SubProduct to terminate specific instances. However, I only tested in non-production. In nonproduction, we have two tags:

1. ****Environment** = nonprod**
2. ****SubEnvironment** = testing, dev, uat**

This is the function:

```
def manage_instances(env, sub_product):
        
        for inst in paginator.paginate(Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:SubProduct',
                'Values': [
                        sub_product,
                ]
            },
            {
                'Name': 'tag:SubEnvironment',
                'Values': [
                        env,
                ]
            },
        ]):
```

In production, when I tried to run the script it returned nothing and I realized it's because the SubEnvironment tag is not populated in production. I could change this so production also has the tag, but out of interest is there a way to specify multiple tag names in the one filter?

I'm trying something like the below but this also doesn't work

```
 def manage_instances(env, sub_product):
        
        for inst in paginator.paginate(Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:SubProduct',
                'Values': [
                        sub_product,
                ]
            },
            {
                'Name': 'tag:Environment','tag:SubEnvironment',
                'Values': [
                        env,
                ]
            },
        ]):
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Name expects a string, you want to provide a list, it won't work.
If you add `tag:SubEnvironment` as a new tag, it won't match in prod, so you won't get the results you want either.

You already have a solution in mind, maybe another way could be that you can simply check your environment and rearrange your filters according to that.

This means you need to know where you are running your code, prod or non-prod (always a good thing to know) and build the filter differently so that by default you do not have SubEnvironment but once you detect that you are in production, you add the SubEnvironment tag.

Pseudo-code

```
def new_filter(environment, subenvironment=None):
   
   filters = [{...}]
   if subenvironment is not None:
        filters.append({'Name': 'tag:SubEnvironment',
                        'Values': [...]})
```